# Custom scrollbar with md-virtual-repeat-scroller

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to custom the md-virtual-repeat-scroller with a cross browser solution without `jQuery`.

I learned that the angular-material team won't implement it : [scrollBar: customize scrollbar UX per Material Design specifications. #5064](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5064)

Is there someone who achieveed to do it ? For the moment I use this `CSS` solution using webkit but it's not supported everywhere.

```
.md-virtual-repeat-scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: $grey;
}

.md-virtual-repeat-scroller::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 6px;
    background-color: $grey;
}

.md-virtual-repeat-scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: $primary;
}
```

Thanks.